# IOS BLE Background - Different behaviors between different devices

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm currently developing an IOS application based on bluetooth low energy and I'm encountering trouble to make it work in background since IOS 10s release.

The application works this way :
Each device acts as CBCentral and CBPeripheral and properties are set in XCode to make it work while in background. The use case is quite simple, when one device is in background and the other one is in foreground, the foreground one will scan for peripherals, discover the backgrounded one, and subscribe to a characteristic. Meanwhile, when the backgrounded one is discovered, it "wakes up" and start scanning for peripheral too, find the device in foreground and subscribe to the same characteristic.

Everything worked fine until the IOS 10s release. Now, with the **same code** on **different devices** the application doesn't works the same. I have :

1. An Iphone 6 on IOS 10.0.2
2. An Iphone SE on IOS 10.0.2
3. An Iphone 4 on IOS 9.3.5
4. An Ipod touch on IOS 9.3.5

When the background device is the [Iphone 6 - 10.0.2] and the foreground device is either the [Iphone SE - 10.0.2] or the [Ipod touch - 9.3.5], the background device **does not scan back** (or does not find the services published by the foreground one, I don't really know), so it's a one-way transmission, only the foreground device get informations from the backgrounded one.

When the background device is the [Iphone 6 - 10.0.2] and the foreground device is the [Iphone 4 - 9.3.5] it works great, the background device subscribe to the foreground one's characteristic.

When the background device is the [Iphone SE - 10.0.2] and the foreground one is either the [Iphone 4 - 9.3.5] or the [Ipod touch - 9.3.5] it also works fine.

Do anyone know what can cause such divergency ?

Thanks